# Error in changing string to datetime object

Tags: python

So I have `test_date1 = "2017-07-21-10-20"` and I want to convert to 
`day1 = datetime.strptime(test_date1, "%y-%m-%d-%h-%M")` but I get the following error :

`time data '2017-07-21-10-20' does not match format '%y-%m-%d-%H-%M'`

What are the proper fields for hours and minutes?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: time data '2017-07-21-10-20' does not match format '%y-%m-%d-%H-%M'

Comment: For 4 digit year use upper case `Y`: `"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M` should work

Answer (score 2):

Use capital H for hour. Check this:

```
datetime.strptime(test_date1, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

below code is working

```
datetime.strptime("2017-07-21-10-20",'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use capital `Y` for "century" year.

`datetime.strptime(test_date1, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")`

Reference: http://strftime.org/

> %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.  2013